# SQL column name period (.) *

Tags: sql

I read the following query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM my_table AS a JOIN your_table AS b ON ...
```

What is `a.*` and what does it mean/do?

Comment: it means ALL Fields from table `my_table` which is using `a` as an alias!

Comment: Did you execute the query? Read any basic SQL tutorial?

Comment: `.` is how you refer columnname from tablename (or tablename from schemaname), `*` means all. So `a.*` means select all column values from table a

Comment: read it on here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html

Comment: They don't give a table to use with the query though

Comment: Question got down voted 6 X then up voted 4 X. Why?

Comment: I downvoted because the `*` operator would certainly be covered in any basic SQL text.

Comment: I would say that this question was downvoted because it shows lack of effort in a research. I didn't downvote nor upvoted though.

Comment: Thanks @ShreyasChavan. You could've posted it as an answer though not a comment.

Comment: It's all good. I did not know how to word it in Google since I didn't know what it was.

Comment: That is the main reason that I don't downvote any questions anymore. Because there are two types of people The one that is lazy enough to search OR, your case, the ones that simple doesn't know how or what to search about a problem. And there is no way to differ then two.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Even the most basic primer on SQL would cover this. Stackoverflow is not a substitute for doing basic background reading on technologies.

Comment: @MartinSmith this particular form of idiom is no int MySql's own tutorial. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html

Comment: Read a proper SQL book. Vendor docs aren't going to teach you SQL efficiently.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the tip. Which do you recommend, there are so many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "all columns from table `a`", which in your example refers to `my_table`.

If you want a specific column, you could do something like:

`SELECT a.columnName, a.anotherColumn FROM my_table AS a JOIN your_table AS b ON ...`

If you wanted all columns from `a` and `b`, you would do:

`SELECT a.*, b.* FROM my_table AS a JOIN your_table AS b ON ...`

Or if you want some from a, and all from b:

`SELECT a.columnName, a.anotherColumn, b.* FROM my_table AS a JOIN your_table AS b ON ...`

Comment: Try reading a Postgres tutorial instead of the documentation first.  You'll probably have an easier go of it  :)